# Print out failed SQL statement in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to print out a failed SQL statement in CodeIgniter. On my first try I used a try/catch block below that prints db->last_query(). However, as you can see from the log the SQL statement is not printed. What am I doing wrong?

```
public function get($limit = NULL, $offset = NULL, $sort = NULL, $search = NULL)
{
    try {
        if ($limit !== NULL) $limit = (int) $limit;
        if ($offset !== NULL) $offset = (int) $offset;
        if (is_array($sort)) {
            foreach ($sort as $field => $order) {
                $this->db->order_by($field, $order);
            }
        }
        if (is_array($search)) {
            foreach ($search as $field => $match) {
                $this->db->where($field, $match);
            }
        }
        $this->db->select($this->select_fields);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name, $limit, $offset);

        // Set the results
        $this->last_query = $this->db->last_query();    
        $this->num_rows = $query->num_rows();
        $this->result_array = $query->result_array();
        $this->db_result = $query;
        $this->error_number = $this->db->_error_number();
        $this->error_message = $this->db->_error_message();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        log_message('error',$e->getMessage());  
        log_message('error',$this->db->last_query());   
        $this->error_number = 500;      
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
DEBUG - 2013-03-02 15:16:50 --> DB Transaction Failure
ERROR - 2013-03-02 15:16:50 --> Query error: Unknown column 'template' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: I think this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15860744/1199612

Answer (score 2):

The $this->db->last_query() line returns the last query **that was run**.

But your SQL log file show us that you have a error in your SQL query. So, your query was not run. The last_query() line can not return anything.

```
Query error: Unknown column 'template' in 'where clause'
```

Do you have a template column in your table?

Comment: Guicara, thanks for the comment. I guess I'm trying to log the complete SQL statement that failed to run. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check if you have "$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;" on your /config/database.php configuration file (TRUE by default). If it's on TRUE, the database errors will be displayed... with the SQL query!

Answer (score 0):

-Simple solution.
-if you are using firfox. than istall firbug and enable it,and in firebug console you can view any thing related your request,like
   - Your http request
   - post/get data
   - responses etc