# How can I catch the database error without letting it end up dead?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, postgresql

What I'm doing is updating a row using Codeigniter active records. DBMS is PostgreSQL. I want to catch the error without ending up with a screen like below.

[image]

If I explain the reason to follow this procedure is, If the update query function is executed correctly without errors there is second function to be executed depending on the return value(true or false) of the 1st function.

I have tried the below methods which do not work.

## Method 1

```
    $this->db->where('id', $folio_id);
    $this->db->update('folio', $data);
    if(!empty($this->db->_error_number()))
    {
    echo "ERROR";die;
    }
```

## Method 2

```
    try
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $folio_id);
        $this->db->update('folio', $data);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
       echo "ERROR";die;
    }
```

All I want to do is return true if the query executed without errors else return false if there are any errors.

How can I catch the database error without letting it end up dead?

Comment: Try with this.. you need to change a little bit CI to have exceptions > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858372/codeigniter-try-catch-is-not-working-in-model-class

Comment: At second thought you can change the error displaying instead to skip core changes..
You may just set the db error to equals default 500 error page..
This way you wont need to try catch at all..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand very well, but why you don't remove the die from the catch ?

```
$success = true;
try
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $folio_id);
        $this->db->update('folio', $data);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
       echo "ERROR ".$e.getMessage();
       $success = false;
    } 

if ($success) {
   ...
```