# MySQL Duplicate Entry Creates Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, unique

In order to avoid a user creating duplicate data I use a `UNIQUE` constraint on a field. Everything works perfect until a duplicate entry; which immediately gives me an internal server error. I am using **CodeIgniter** for queries and check database errors using `$this->db->_error_message()` yet instead of being handled the program seems to exit and the error number is returned on my **AJAX** call. 
Is there another way of handling these types of errors or is it something I am doing wrong?

Comment: you might wanna post relevant code.

Comment: Sounds like an Exception gets thrown, and you neglected to catch it properly.

Comment: @CBroe What was it that threw the exception and how do I handle it?

Comment: see if you are getting any error on apache error_log or whatever webserver you are using

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a duplicate will throw the exeption.

Try to catch it like this:

```
try
{
    // insertin the duplicate
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Exeption: '.  $e->getMessage();
}
```

More about exception handling: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: That did not work. After the duplicate error is fired execution stops completely and the `try/catch` block does not do anything.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858372/codeigniter-try-catch-is-not-working-in-model-class