# Try catch block not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, try-catch

Try catch block not working in codeigniter.

```
try {
        echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom exception handling in codeigniter.
Try with with following links :

1. http://thecancerus.com/simple-way-to-add-global-exception-handling-in-codeigniter/
2. [CodeIgniter: Try Catch is not working in model class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858372/codeigniter-try-catch-is-not-working-in-model-class)