# Codeigniter 3: Can't catch database error using try catch block

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm working on an api, it handles the requests which comes from clients, then gets the response from server(developed using codeigniter 3) and forwards that back to client.

But, in case of any database errors, like duplicate id, or null values, the model class cannot handle that error to display a proper error message. I've tried the try catch block but not succeeded yet.
Here's the model:

```
public function add() {
    try {
        $this->db->trans_start(FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('users', $preparedData);
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception("Database error:");
            return false;
        }
        return TRUE;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        log_message('error: ',$e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
}
```

One thing to mention, I've set db_debug to FALSE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Before inserting please check the value in database

Comment: I tried checking, but still it is not displaying error.

Comment: How are you validating it? Can you please update the question with check code before insert?

Comment: You can refer this for solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732546/mysql-error-handling-try-catch/44732919#44732919

Comment: you can check solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858372/codeigniter-try-catch-is-not-working-in-model-class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As for CI 3, below code gets database *error code* and *error message*.  db_debug is set to FALSE.

```
public function add() {
    try {
        $this->db->trans_start(FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('users', $preparedData);
        $this->db->trans_complete();

        // documentation at
        // https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#handling-errors
        // says; "the error() method will return an array containing its code and message"
        $db_error = $this->db->error();
        if (!empty($db_error)) {
            throw new Exception('Database error! Error Code [' . $db_error['code'] . '] Error: ' . $db_error['message']);
            return false; // unreachable retrun statement !!!
        }
        return TRUE;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // this will not catch DB related errors. But it will include them, because this is more general. 
        log_message('error: ',$e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
}
```

Refer to documentation at https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#handling-errors

saying

> If you need to get the last error that has occurred, the error() method will return **an array** containing its *code* and *message*.

It is a bit incomplete in my opinion because it does not show error code and error message in the example code.

Comment: Using CI 3.1.5, $this->db->error() always return a non empty array, thus I had to test if(! $db_error['code']) to make this solution work.

Comment: immediately after each statement you have to check the result of the statement and keep error in a variable and later if trans result is false use that error variable, please check my solution

Answer (score 0):

I just lost an hour trying to figure out why I can't get the error in my code. **You have to check for an error after each statement!** Working solution:

```
  function insertUpdate($data) {

    $order = $data->order;
    $order_products = $data->order_products;

    $this->db->trans_start();

    $order->user_id = $this->session->user_id;

    $error = "OK";

    if (!$this->db->insert('_order', $order)) {
      $error = $this->db->error()["message"];
    }

    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    foreach ($order_products as $row) {
      $row->order_id = $id;
      if (!$this->db->insert('_order_product', $row)) {
        $error = $this->db->error()["message"];
        break;
      }
    }

    $order_code = substr(md5($id), 0, 6);

    if (!$this->db->where('order_id', $id)) {
      $error = $this->db->error()["message"];
    }

    if (!$this->db->update('_order', ["order_code" => $order_code])) {
      $error = $this->db->error()["message"];
    }

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return [
        'result' => $error, 'order_code' => $order_code
    ];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion in above code

- Remove line `$this->db->trans_complete();`
- If we see  `$this->db->error()`  after completing transaction it will be always empty
- Remove semicolon - `log_message('error :',$e->getMessage());
      return;`

```
    public function add()
    {
    try {
        $this->db->trans_start(FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('users', $preparedData);


        // documentation at
        // https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#handling-errors
        // says; "the error() method will return an array containing its code and message"
        $db_error = $this->db->error();
        if (!empty($db_error)) {
            throw new Exception('Database error! Error Code [' . $db_error['code'] . '] Error: ' . $db_error['message']);
            return false; // unreachable return statement !!!`enter code here`
        }
        return TRUE;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // this will not catch DB related `enter code here`errors. But it will include them, because this is more general. 
        log_message('error ',$e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
    }
```

Comment: you can't remove $this->db->trans_complete() when you have trans_start