# Mysql error handling/Try catch

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, try-catch, codeigniter-3

If table column does not exist mysql shows error .How to fix it using try catch or error handling method

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Example:  Query:"select name,age from example

Comment: If name column is not there then mysql will show an error .I want to catch that error

Comment: Is there any way to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried something like : IF COL_LENGTH('schemaName.tableName', 'columnName') IS NOT NULL BEGIN  (col exists, so enter queries here) END

Comment: I am trying above thing in codeigniter

Comment: I have mentioned simple example to explain what i am looking for.I want a way to handle database errors like try catch.is it possible?

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @SwatiB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can handle the `mysql` `error` in this way

```
 if ( ! $this->db->query('SELECT `name`,`age` FROM `example`'))
{
        $error = $this->db->error(); // Has keys 'code' and 'message'
}
```

Comment: For those who are looking for try catch in mysql/codeignter can refer following:

Comment: try {
            if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
                throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error());
            }
     
            $result = $this->db->query('SELECT `name`,`age` FROM `example`');
            if (!$result) {
                $error = $this->db->error(); // Has keys 'code' and 'message'
                throw new Exception($error["message"]);
                return false;
            }

            return $result;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($e);
        }