# How to catch database exceptions?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Inside a controller I want to make an insert into the database :

```
public function insertAction() {

        try {
            $this->load->model('action');
            $_POST['laDate'] = $this->input->post('ladate_') == '' ? '' : $this->dates->convertDateToFormatBase($this->input->post('ladate_'), '');
            $_POST['dateCreation'] = "now()";
            $action_id = $this->action->ajouter($_POST);
            if (isset($_POST['verificateurs'])) {
                $this->load->model('actionVerificateur');
                $this->actionVerificateur->inserer($action_id, $_POST['verificateurs']);
            }
            $this->load->view('ajax/insertAction', array('action_id' => $action_id));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->load->view('ajax/insertAction', array('action_id' => 0));
        }

    }
```

There is a `unique` constraint on some columns of the database table. So when this constraint is violated then I want to catch the exception. But it seems that my code does not catch it ! So how to catch the exception ?

Comment: what if you use `Transactions`. I never heard of using  TRY CATCH in the framework. Cz Framework helps thing easy. But you doing old still

Comment: yeah , old school here lol :)

Comment: Check this out, this helped me earlier. Hope it will be helpful to you also. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858372/codeigniter-try-catch-is-not-working-in-model-class

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround : I tested if `$this->db->insert_id()` is numeric ! because in the case an exception is raised then the returned value is an html code beggining with `<DOCTYPE>`.