# Custom way to log the exception in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to build an exception handler for codeIgniter that triggers when an error occurs, and it will record all input that caused the exception and the output the exception gave in a clean neat format in a text file.

As far I could only record the exception in log file using log function. in the error_db template file I extracted the message value and inserted it into log file.

```
   <div id="container">
    <h1><?php echo $heading; ?></h1>
    <?php echo $message; 

     $formatted_msg = str_replace('</p>','',$message);
     $formatted_msgs = explode('<p>',$formatted_msg);
     $messages = $formatted_msgs[1].'    -->    '.$formatted_msgs[4].'    -->    '.$formatted_msgs[5];
     log_message('error',$messages);

    ?>
</div>
```

I want to show the result like: What function,what input and which line caused the exception and output produced. Now I am getting data like

```
    ERROR - 2019-04-16 15:28:40 --> Error Number: 1054    -->    Filename: file_path/system/database/DB_driver.php    -->    Line Number: 691
```

Comment: i would suggest looking in to `Exceptions.php`, the `_error_handler` function in `Common.php` as well as the native php function `debug_backtrace`. You will probably have to make some modifications to CI's core code.

Comment: Ok I'll look into it .Thank you @Alex

Comment: I followed this method and got the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858372/codeigniter-try-catch-is-not-working-in-model-class/15860744

Comment: just to make sure, you followed all of the persons recommendations right? because otherwise, the code you posted will just work for exceptions (not php errors/warnings) thrown in the try block.

Comment: Yes , followed all of the recommendations. Thanks again. @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this method and got the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860744/11367846

And added some customization for my requirement. In the controller page in exception catch added code for customized log.

```
public function controller_method( )
{
try
{
    // normal flow
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    $trace = $e->getTrace();

    $result = 'Exception: "';
    $result .= $e->getMessage();
    $result .= '" @ ';
    if($trace[4]['file'] != '') {
      $result .= ' File : '.$trace[4]['file'].'::: Line : '.$trace[4]['line'].' ::: Source :'.$trace[5]['class'].' -> '.$trace[5]['function'].' ::: Function : '.$trace[4]['class'].' -> '.$trace[4]['function'].' ::: Inputs :'.http_build_query($trace[4]['args']);
    }

    log_message( 'error', $result );
}
```

}